# Ошибка при запуске Android SDK

Tags: android-sdk, debian

При попытке запустить Android SDK, выскакивает ошибка:

> SWT folder '/usr/lib/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/arm' does not exist.
>   Please export ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.

Запускаю в папке tools, командой (как написано в инструкции):

> ./android

Как это исправить?

P.S. ОС: Debian Wheeze. Извините, если вопрос был, но выдало гугле я не понял, что нужно делать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала в корне директории tools введите команду, чтоб найти расположение swt:

```
find . -name swt.jar
```

Затем экспортните её:

```
export ANDROID_SWT= <путь к swt из предыдущего пункта>
```

Должно быть что-то типо:

```
export ANDROID_SWT=${ANDROID_SDK}/tools/lib/x86_64/
```

Это если не ARM. Для ARM надо ручками собирать SDK (так как Google не предоставляет Android SDK для arm), например, по [этой](http://www.timelesssky.com/blog/building-android-sdk-build-tools-aapt-for-debian-arm) статье.